# problems with laravel eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm learning the MVC pattern using Laravel and the eloquent model is kinda overwhelming to me. The eloquent model returns a collection of columns of a table, but I want to a collection of another table to be the attributes of that model.

I have 3 tables

**Books**

```
id,
title
```

**Contribution**

```
book_id,
contributor_id,
role
```

**Author**

```
id,
name
```

I want to change the return values of function like all(), find(), get() and etc of model Books to include the contributors

From this:

```
[  "id" => "1", 
   "title" => "CS101" 
]
```

To this:

```
[ "id" => "1",
  "title" => "CS101",
  "contributors" => [
   [
    "id" => "1",
    "name" => "Einstein"
    "role" => "author"
   ],
   [
    "id" => "2",
    "name" => "Thomas"
    "role" => "translator"
   ]
  ]
]
```

Should I not use Eloquent and build my own model or is there a function of eloquent that I can override or any better way to do this

Comment: this is the relationship reason to live :) before you get all() you need to add $this->model->with('relationmodelname')->all(); or Model::with('realationship1','relationshipX')->all();

Comment: @StefanoMartini just a heads up, `->all()` cannot be called after other Builder methods; `Model::with(...)->all()` triggers the error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()`. Correct syntax is either `Model::all()`, or `Model::with(...)->get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create the relation between `Book::class` and `Author::class`

Book.php

```
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
 
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The Author that belong to the book.
     */
    public function contributors(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Author::class, 'contribution', 'book_id', 'contributor_id')->withPivot('role');
    }
}
```

Then you can load the relation when you run your query

```
$books = Book::with('contributors')->get();

$book = Book::with('contributors')->first();
```

This will result in the structure

```
[
  "id" => "1",
  "title" => "CS101",
  "contributors" => [
    [
      "id" => "1",
      "name" => "Einstein",
      "pivot" => [
        "role" => "Author",
      ]
    ],
    [
      "id" => "2",
      "name" => "Thomas"
      "pivot" => [
        "role" => "Translator",
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

The most interesting is that this way, the relation will be eager loaded meaning that only two queries will be run to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Please see:

- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships
- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Once you properly define your model relations, you can use `with` function to pull additional data with your base model:

```
$books = Book::with('author')->get();
 
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->author->name;
}
```

Comment: You should add the relation definition to your answer since the structure is not conventional.

Comment: I could, but decided I would not. Feel free to do it yourself. The OP is able to read documentation I assume.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make proper relations in model first.

Book.php

```
public function contributors() {
   return $this->hasMany( Contribution:class );
}
```

Contribution.php

```
public function books() {
 return $this->belongsTo( Book:class );
}
```

Now you should be able to use these relationships in controller like this:

```
$books = Book::with('contributors')->get();
```

In contributors array, you need to make relations again in the respective model to get the name of author.

*Feel free to ask further doubts*

Comment: Contributor is not a model, the table does have an "ID" because it is a pivot table between Books and Authors. the relation should be belongToMany

Comment: Also, `Contribution:class` is not valid PHP. To access a "Class String", you use `::`, so `Contribution::class` and `Book::class`.